# reading and writing to a file in python

Tags: python

I have the following python script, where I want to make some modifications to the image src paths and then write those back into the same file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import re
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML

azure = ['cdn.core.windows.net', 'blob.core.windows.net']
walk_dir = ["www", "sites"]

image_paths = []
for x in walk_dir:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x, topdown=False):
      for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
          f_content = f.read()
          if filename.endswith('.html'):
            soup = BSHTML(f_content)
            images = soup.findAll('img')
            print(filename, file_path)
            for image in images:
              try:
                image_src = image['src'].split('?')
                print(image_src)
                image_paths.append(image_src[0])
              except:
                pass
```

I am unclear what the best way would be to now take the `image_src` and re-write it and then at the end save the file once all the images have been updated?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Open your file (like you already do), read it and store content in a variable. Then close the file (just get out of the `with` block). Do your stuff on the content, then reopen your file in `w` or `wb` mode, and write down this new content.

Comment: Why do you check if filename.endswith('.html'): AFTER open the file?

Comment: you are correct @Wonka have corrected this

Comment: First of all, if you want to overwrite you file, you have to use open(file_path, 'r+b'). 'rb' allows only to read a binary file. the + allows for writing/editing as well. Second, can you make you question clearer? Are you having trouble locating where the changes should be? or how to save the new file?

Comment: how to modify the existing file and then save it